# Why .config directory is not listed when excluded from gitignore using wildcard (*) and git status?

Tags: git, config

I know the question is a bit cryptic, I couldn't word it exactly in a single sentence (*might need some help on that*).

I initialized git in my home directory (i.e, `~/`, on **Arch Linux**) to backup my dot-files (mainly configs). I want to include every file and folder in it except the ones starting with a `.` (like `.config/` and `.bashrc`).

So I made a `.gitignore` file whose contents are:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Except these files and folders
!.*
```

But the problem is when I list all the untracked files (`git status`), it doesn't list the `.config/` directory for some reason. I tried playing around with `.gitignore` and adding

```
!*/
```

shows all directories including `.config/` and also `Documents`, `Downloads` etc, which I don't want to include.

And instead adding

```
!.*/
```

shows every other directory that starts with a `.` like `.cache/`, `.vim/` etc. But for some reason the `.config/` doesn't show up.

I even tried

```
!.config/
```

and

```
!.config
```

it doesn't work. The only thing that works is `!*/` (all directories, which is not what I want)

Any way to solve this. Its really annoying.

**[Solved]:** *[it was a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098335/why-config-directory-is-not-listed-when-excluded-from-gitignore-using-wildcard#comment123918197_70098335)*

**The bug has been fixed in git version 2.34.1**

Check [the accepted answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70101507/12033855)

Comment: Did you initialize the home directory itself or create a directory for your repo within the home directory? .i.e ~/my-repo/{initilized_here}

Comment: Has `.config` already been added? `.gitignore` only affects files that aren't already added.

Comment: Initialized the home directory i.e, `cd ~; git init`

Comment: @ikegami No, I just initialized git, nothing else done

Comment: oh wait, is there anything in `.config`? git doesn't deal with dirs, only files. If there's no files in `.config`, it won't list it

Comment: @ikegami Yes there are so many config files and folders inside `.config`. And I kinda figured a way around it, but don't exactly know why. I added both `!.*` and `!.*/*` and it works. It lists all files and folders starting with `.`. It doesn't work when `!.*/*` is alone, it only works when both are present. It does make some sense as one of the conditions for `.gitignore` is that  **if the parent dir is ignored then the children cant be excluded without excluding the parent**. I think it has something to do with that, like maybe `*` includes the current directory as well (i.e., `./`) ? Idk

Comment: I get the behaviour you describe for [every folder](https://gist.github.com/ikegami/74e7e53a6be9a3ef77c0d275f12960c2), not just `.config`

Comment: I don't understand why, try adding `!.*/*` along with `!.*`

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: `git version 2.34.0`

Comment: There's a bug in directory-only matching in 2.34.0. The fix is in Git, `make install` fixes it for me, I'd think there'll be an official release real soon now.

Comment: @jthill Oh, thank you so much. Even tho I partially solved it I was still encountering the problem again. I will be on the look out for the update. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR

After the bug fix, you'll want what you put in your "kinda solved" section, or something similar.  I think you'll want what I put in my "bottom line" section, really:

```
/*
!/.*
```

## Long

As [jthill noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098335/why-config-directory-is-not-listed-when-excluded-from-gitignore-using-wildcard#comment123918197_70098335), there is a bug in the `.gitignore` wildcard handling in Git 2.34.0, which will be fixed in 2.34.1.  In this case I think the bug is making your wildcarding work *better* than it would otherwise, though.

The first lines:

```
# Ignore everything
*
```

do just what they claim: ignore *everything*.  All files and folders (directories) are ignored.  Subsequent lines insert exceptions.  But hang on a moment, what does *ignored* really mean?  To get there, we must note what Git's *index* (or *staging area*) is and how Git makes new commits from the index / staging-area.

The index, or staging area, in Git, is a central and crucial concept.  Trying to use Git without understanding what the index is doing is a bit like trying to pilot an airplane without understanding what the wings and engine are for.<sup>1</sup>  So: the index is all about the *next commit you plan to make*.  If you never make any new commits, you don't *really* need to know about it, but if you *do* want to make new commits, you need to know this.<sup>2</sup>

When you first extract some commit, in order to use and work on it, Git fills in its index *from* that commit, so that the index contains all the files from that commit.  From this point onward, everything you are doing in your working tree, in the pursuit of making a new commit, is *irrelevant to Git*.  That is, it's irrelevant *up until you tell Git that you'd like Git to copy updated and/or new files into Git's index.*

The `git add` command is about updating Git's index.  The files you name to `git add`, with `git add file1 file2` for instance, are to be copied into Git's index.  If there's already a copy of those two files, those copies get booted out of the index, replaced with the updated ones.  If not, those files are newly added *to* the index.

Once a file *is in the index*, you can *replace* it at any time: any `.gitignore` entry is irrelevant at this point.  You can also *remove it from the index*, with `git rm`, or by using `git add` after removing the working tree copy: either one will remove the index copy.  Now it's *no longer in the index* and the `.gitignore` entries are back in play.

You can use an en-masse `git add`, as in `git add .` or `git add *`,<sup>3</sup> to have Git *scan* directories and files and add them for you.  When you do this, Git will *skip* certain directories and/or files if it can, and this is an area where `.gitignore` really comes into play.

---

<sup>1</sup>"Why should I care about those?  I only care about getting my passengers and cargo from point A to point B, and those are inside the plane, not out on the wings."

<sup>2</sup>To extend the plane analogy a bit more: if you're just planning to use the fuselage as a house, then indeed, you don't need to care about the engines and wings.

<sup>3</sup>Note that in Unix-like shells, `git add *` is quite different from `git add .` because the *shell* will expand `*` for Git: Git never sees the literal asterisk.  When the shell expands `*`, it does so with dot-files excluded, by default at least (bash in particular has a control knob to change this behavior).  In some CLIs, the literal asterisk `*` gets through to Git, and then *Git* will expand `*`, and now it can act like `git add .` if Git wants it to.  But it's easier to type in `git add .` (no <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key required) so that's what I always do anyway, which removes the difference in the first place.

---

#### How Git scans the working tree

If you run `git add .` or equivalent (see footnote 3 again), Git will:

1. Open the directory `.`.
2. Open and read any `.gitignore` file at this level, adding (appending) these rules to the ignore rules.  (These rules then get dropped when we finish this directory.)
3. Read this directory: it contains the names of files and sub-directories ("folders", if you prefer that term).
4. Check each file and folder name as we read them, against all the ignore rules that are in effect right now.  Note that some rules apply *only to directories / folders*, and others apply to *both folders and files*.  The folder-only rules are those that end with a slash.  Also, some rules are "positive" (do ignore) and some are "negative" (do not ignore).  The negative rules are the ones starting with `!`.

Git finds the *last applicable rule*, whatever that is, in the current set of rules, and then obeys that rule.  So first, let's define which rules apply to which directory-scan results, and then what the various rules do.

A rule in a `.gitignore` can be:

- a simple text string with *no* slashes, such as `generated.file`;
- a text string with a trailing slash, but no other slashes: `somedir/`;
- a text string with a leading or embedded slash, with or without a trailing slash: `/foo`, `a/b`, `/foo/`, `a/b/`, and so on; or
- any of the above with various [*glob*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))-style wildcard characters.

These can all be negated: if a rule starts with `!` it's negated, and we strip off the `!` and then use the remaining tests.  The two keys tests are these:

- Does the entry *end with* a literal `/`?  If so, it applies only to directories / folders.  Ignore that slash while answering the remaining question.
- Does the entry *begin with* or *contain* a slash `/` character?  (The one at the end does not count here.)  If so, this entry is *anchored* or *rooted* (I like the term *anchored* myself, but I've seen both terms used).

An *anchored* entry matches only a file or folder name found *at this level*.  That is, `/foo` or `foo/bar` won't match `sub/foo` or `sub/foo/bar`, only `./foo` and `./foo/bar`, where `.` is the directory (folder) that Git is scanning *right now*.  This means that if the entry has several levels—`foo/bar` or `one/two/three` for instance—Git will have to remember to apply this entry when it gets around to scanning `bar` in `foo`, or `two` in `one` and `three` in `one/two`.  So we do have to consider "higher level" rules.  But since lower level rules get *appended*, a lower level `.gitignore` can cancel out the higher level one if it wants to.

An *un-anchored entry* applies here and—unless overridden—in *every sub-directory as well*.  That is, if we do have `./one/two/three`, Git will presumably open and read `one` to find `two`, and then open and read `two` to find `three`, all *while still working on the current directory*.  Meanwhile *any* un-anchored entry *from this `.gitignore`* will apply *within* the `one` and `one/two` directories, and within `one/two/three` if that's a directory, and so on.

So, there's already a lot to think about.  Now we throw in glob matches.

The usual glob is `*`: people write `foo*bar` or `*.pyc` or whatever.  Git allows `**` as well, with meaning similar to that in bash: zero or more directories.  (I've found `**` in Git to be weird and in my opinion slightly buggy, where it sometimes seems to mean "one or more" instead of "zero or more", so I recommend avoiding `**` if possible.  It's hard to reason about, so it's generally not a great idea in the first place, and Git's ignore rules mostly eliminate any need for `**`.  So if you *are* going to use it, test it carefully and be prepared to have it shift on you in some future Git, in case the one-or-more ?bug? gets fixed, or affects your use case, or whatever.)

Let's suppose, then, that we have these two entries:

```
*
!.*
```

Git opens and reads `.` and finds the following names:

```
dir
file
.dir
.file
```

where `dir` and `.dir` are directories (folders) and `file` and `.file` are non-directories (files).

The `*` rule matches all four names.  The `!.*` rule matches the last two names.  The `!.*` rule is later in the `.gitignore` file, so it overrides the `*` rule.  Git therefore "sees" `.dir` and `.file`.

Since `.file` *is* a file, this means that `git add .` "sees" it.  It will check whether `.file` needs to be `git add`-ed to displace the existing `.file` file, or added to the index.

Since `dir` and `file` are excluded, this scanning pass *doesn't* see them, and does not try to `git add` either one.  Since `dir` itself is a *directory* (not a file), it's never in the index itself.  There may be a file in the index *named* `dir/thing`, and Git will check to see if that should be updated by this `git add .`, but Git won't *scan* `dir` to see if there are other files *in* `dir`.

Since `file` is an excluded file, the scanning pass does not see it.  But if `file` already exists in the index, Git will check to see if it should be updated by this `git add .`, even though it didn't get *scanned* here.  In other words, these "existing files already in the index" checks happen *outside* (either before or after) the "scan the directories" pass.

Meanwhile, since `.dir` *isn't* excluded, Git now opens and reads `.dir`, recursively:

- Git checks for a `.dir/.gitignore` (the `.gitignore` that applies to entries found in `.dir`).  If that exists, Git appends those rules.
- Git scans `.dir` recursively, using all the same methods.  Then it's done scanning `.dir` so Git removes the appended rules.

Let's look now at the rules Git has in effect as it scans `.dir`.

#### The appended-to rules

If there is a `.dir/.gitignore`, Git opens and reads it and appends to the existing rules.  If not, we still have the same set of rules in effect:

```
*     (positive wildcard: ignore every name)
!.*   (negative wildcard: don't ignore dot-names)
```

What's in `.dir`?  Let's say we have:

```
file1
dir1
.file2
.dir2
```

The name `file1` matches `*` so *it gets ignored*.  Git won't `git add` it to the index if it's not already there.  Similarly, `dir1` matches `*`, so *it gets ignored*.  Git won't even *scan* it to see if there are any files there.

The name `.file2` matches `*`, but also matches `.*`, so the override negative entry is the rule that applies: Git will `git add .dir/.file2`.  The name `.dir2` has the same features, so the override applies and Git will *open and read* `.dir/.dir2`.  This goes through the same recursion as before: Git looks for `.dir/.dir2/.gitignore` to *append* rules, and will use the appended-to rules while scanning `.dir/.dir2`, and then drop back to our own `.dir/.gitignore`-appended rule set while continuing to scan `.dir`, and then return from this recursion level and drop the `.dir/.gitignore` rules.

#### The bottom line

In the end, the trick here is that we want the `*` rule to apply *only at the top level*.  Once we get into, say, `.foo/`, we don't want to ignore `.foo/main_config` and `.foo/secondary_config`.  So we want `*` to apply *only at the top level*.

Using:

```
# Ignore everything
*

# Except these files and folders
!.*
!.*/*
```

gets us closer: we ignore everything, but then—via the negative rules `!.*` and `!.*/*`—we carefully *don't* ignore `.foo` and the like.  Once we get *into* `.foo`, we carefully *don't* ignore `.foo/main_config`.

The bug, or possible bug, depending on what you really do want, here is ... well, suppose we have `.foo/thing1/config` and `.foo/thing2/config`.  The `.*/*` pattern *contains an embedded slash*, which means it is *anchored*.  It matches `.foo/thing1`, so that directory gets scanned.  But it *doesn't* match `.foo/thing1/config`.

We could try something like:

```
!.*/*
!.*/**/
```

I particularly hate this one because `**` is so tough to reason about.  We could also write:

```
!.*/*
!.*/*/
!.*/**/
```

in case the `**` "one or more" bug bites us (I don't think it will, but it's a consideration).  But it's simplest to *anchor the original globs*, by writing:

```
/*
!/.*
```

This makes the top level `.gitignore` *rules* apply *only* to top-level work-tree *entries*.  Sub-level `.gitignore` files, if they exist, can establish sub-level rules and do not need to override any top-level rules, because the top-level rules *already don't apply at any sub-level*, thanks to anchoring.

Comment: When I started reading this, lesser and lesser made sense. But after half way through I started understanding a lot more. And the bottom line, no idea what it said at first, but I read it again and it just clicked. Amazing answer. Thank you so much for an amazing and in-depth explanation.

Comment: The gitignore rules are ... crazy complicated, mainly for implementation reasons: opening and scanning directories can be slow, so Git tries hard to cut it off early if possible. But that makes explaining the process tricky. And then there are files that are already in Git's index, which messes with the whole process. This is exactly how the bug got into 2.34 in the first place: it's too complicated! :-)

Comment: the new version is released and the bug has been fixed, thanks.